# Cassandra throws error('required argument is not an integer') when I set the consistency level to quorum

Tags: python, cassandra

Here is my table's definition.

```
CREATE TABLE chat_data.twitch_chat_by_broadcaster_and_timestamp (
    broadcaster_id int,
    year_month int,
    timestamp bigint,
    message_id uuid,
    message text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((broadcaster_id, year_month), timestamp, message_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp ASC, message_id ASC)
```

Here is my code to insert.

```
import logging
import auth.secrets as secrets
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.policies import DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy, TokenAwarePolicy
from cassandra.query import BatchStatement, BatchType, tuple_factory
from datetime_helpers import get_month, get_next_month

class DatabaseConnection:
    def __init__(self, keyspace):
        auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(
            secrets.get_astra_client_id(), secrets.get_astra_secret()
        )
        load_balancing_policy = TokenAwarePolicy(DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy())
        cluster = Cluster(
            cloud=secrets.get_astra_cloud_config(),
            auth_provider=auth_provider,
            load_balancing_policy=load_balancing_policy,
        )
        self.session = cluster.connect(keyspace)

    def insert_chats(self, messages):
        logging.info(f"Inserting {len(messages)} message")

        batch = BatchStatement(
            consistency_level="QUORUM", batch_type=BatchType.UNLOGGED
        )

        statement = self.session.prepare(
            """
            INSERT INTO twitch_chat_by_broadcaster_and_timestamp (broadcaster_id, year_month, timestamp, message_id, message)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
            """
        )

        for m in messages:
            broadcaster_id, timestamp, message_id, message = m
            month = get_month(timestamp)
            batch.add(
                statement, (broadcaster_id, month, timestamp, message_id, message)
            )

        try:
            self.session.execute(batch)
            logging.info("Messages inserted successfully")
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Exception: {e}")
            return False
```

`execute` throws

```
Exception: ('Unable to complete the operation against any hosts', {<Host: <astra datastax machine #1>: error('required argument is not an integer'), <Host: <astra datastax machine #2>: error('required argument is not an integer'), <Host: <astra datastax machine #3>>: error('required argument is not an integer')}
```

I printed out the types I'm passing in the `batch.add` statement and confirmed they are correct. I eventually got the database to accept my insertion by removing `consistency_level="QUORUM"` from the BatchStatement. It now reads `batch = BatchStatement(batch_type=BatchType.UNLOGGED)`

Any ideas why I'm only getting the exception when I try to set the consistency level to quorum? Also, what's going on under the hood that's causing this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the consistency level to a string value, instead of the enum `ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM` . The enum is an integer value (https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/master/cassandra/__init__.py#L29)

```
batch = BatchStatement(
        consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM, batch_type=BatchType.UNLOGGED
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why it never occurred to me that `BatchStatement` was throwing the exception instead of `execute`